# CodeIgniter: Different results with active record queries?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, activerecord

I have a function to get records in database like this:

```
public function test_records_with_join($select, $from, $joins=array(), $where, $order_by = null, $limit=null, $offset=null, $or_where=null, $group_by = null, $protect = TRUE){
            if (!$protect) $this->db->_protect_identifiers=false;
            if (is_array($select)){
                foreach ($select as $select){
                    $this->db->select($select, false);
                }
            }else{
                $this->db->select($select, false);    
            }

            $this->db->from($from);
            if (is_array($joins) && count($joins)>0){
                foreach ($joins as $join){
                    $this->db->join($join[0],$join[1],$join[2]);
                }
            }
            foreach ($where as $key => $value) {
                if ($key=='OR_WHERE') {
                    foreach ($value as $or_where_condition){
                        $this->db->where($or_where_condition);
                    }
                }
                else $this->db->where($key, $value, false);
            }

            if (!is_null($order_by)) $this->db->order_by($order_by);
            if (!is_null($group_by)) $this->db->group_by($group_by);

            if (!is_null($limit) && !is_null($offset)) $this->db->limit($limit, $offset);
            $result = $this->db->get();
            **Debug::dump($result);**
            if (isset($data)) unset($data);
            $data = array();
            foreach ($result->result() as $row){
                $data[] = $row;
            }
            echo count($data);
            return $data;
        }
```

**Query 1:**

```
$query1 = $this->_product_model->test_records_with_join('GROUP_CONCAT(pr.id) as promo_ids, pr.updated_date, p.*, b.title as brand_title',
                                'products as p',
                                array(
                                    array('product_brands as b','b.id=p.brand_id','left'),
                                    array('promos as pr','FIND_IN_SET(p.id, pr.product_ids)','left')
                                    ),
                                $where, $order_by, null, null, null, 'p.id', FALSE);



$query2 = $this->_product_model->test_records_with_join('GROUP_CONCAT(pr.id) as promo_ids, pr.updated_date, p.*, b.title as brand_title',
                                    'products as p',
                                    array(
                                        array('product_brands as b','b.id=p.brand_id','left'),
                                        array('promos as pr','FIND_IN_SET(p.id, pr.product_ids)','left')
                                        ),
                                    $where, $order_by, 40, 0, null, 'p.id', FALSE);
```

This is the last executed query :

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(pr.id) as promo_ids, pr.updated_date, p.*, b.title as brand_title
FROM products as p
LEFT JOIN product_brands as b ON b.id=p.brand_id
LEFT JOIN promos as pr ON FIND_IN_SET(p.id, pr.product_ids)
WHERE p.visible = 1
AND p.price>=0
AND p.price<=2500000
GROUP BY p.id
ORDER BY p.price DESC
LIMIT 40
```

**UPDATE:**

Executing those queries gave me this :

```
object(CI_DB_mysql_result)#150 (8) {
  ["conn_id"] => resource(40) of type (mysql link)
  ["result_id"] => resource(189) of type (mysql result)
  ["result_array"] => array(0) {
  }
  ["result_object"] => array(0) {
  }
  ["custom_result_object"] => array(0) {
  }
  ["current_row"] => int(0)
  ["num_rows"] => int(720)
  ["row_data"] => NULL
}

int(720)

object(CI_DB_mysql_result)#1596 (8) {
  ["conn_id"] => resource(40) of type (mysql link)
  ["result_id"] => resource(191) of type (mysql result)
  ["result_array"] => array(0) {
  }
  ["result_object"] => array(0) {
  }
  ["custom_result_object"] => array(0) {
  }
  ["current_row"] => int(0)
  ["num_rows"] => int(40)
  ["row_data"] => NULL
}
```

With the 2nd query (with $per_page = 40, $offset = 0), there is nothing in $data (count it returns nothing). Why? I've tried to unset the $data before initializing it again but nothing happened.

Where did I do wrong? Thanks in advance!

Comment: is the generated query working in mysql console?

Comment: @Torrezzzz : Yes, it works perfect!

Comment: try `var_dump($this->db->last_query());` check the last executed query ...

Comment: the problem may be in the model .... If the query is working without limit means it should work with limit 40 also..... In code you have initialized data as array twice remove it....

Comment: I've tried to unset($data) before init it but the problem is still.